# Locale in Android work immediately after setting

Tags: android, locale, onresume

my problem is i am using below code for setting locale language dynamically. Its changing the default locale but after calling onResume() while i want to run it immediately as i am at very first page of my app.

```
locale = new Locale("de");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: So you want/have to call it `onCreate` ?

Comment: but after the selection of user dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Save choosen language in SharedPref:

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
  editor.putString("Lang",ChoosenLang);
  editor.commit();
```

get Value in  onCreate

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      String Language = preferences.getString("Lang","de");
if (Language != null && !Language.isEmpty()) {
  // Your Language code here

locale = new Locale(Language); // Language=de
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

}
```

Comment: Oli i want to do this after selection of language from user.
Will it work there also?

Comment: Then you should use a dialogbox with the selecion and save it to sharedpref

Comment: Perfect, are u saving it into sharedpref?

Comment: Glad to help you. If you want you could mark my answer as correct ;) - happy coding

Comment: oli sorry for late comment actually my need or requirement is to convert locale language dynamically...
and thanks for help